# Does the search mechanism on the Stack Exchange blog work at all?

Tags: support, blog, search-engine

[This post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-machine-learning-contest/) on blog.stackoverflow.com features this line:

> We’re also hiring a [full-time data scientist](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/19463/stack-exchange-data-scientist-stack-exchange), and we’re going to be very interested in talking to the authors of the best classifiers.

The link is to a now-expired Careers listing.

Note the above text; now try [searching for 'classifiers'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?s=classifiers) and [searching for 'scientist'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?s=scientist), and note the paucity of results.

Am I missing something, or does the blog search just not work at all?

<sub>Perhaps there is a subliminal suggestion in the message "Try a different search?"...</sub>

Comment: It works... somewhat. But not completely. For example, searching for "meta" won't get you anything, but "Meta" will. It's definitely broken, though what the cause is, that is unsure at the moment.